# innerText not working for one column - Can't bind to 'innertext' since it isn't a known property

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am just adding one more column in grid with name `coordinatorName`. To do that, I modified WebApi as needed and saw data, it is fine. I have problem with `Angular2`.

**Component**

```
export class WorkflowActivity{
    activityName: string;
    assigneeName: string;
    coordinatorName: string;
    serviceName: string;
    createdDate: Date;
    dueDate: Date;
    status: string;
    isSelected: boolean;
    isCritical: boolean;
    isForwarded: boolean;
}
```

You can see I have added one column there. And in `Html`.

**Layout**

```
    <tr *ngFor='let activity of pagedWorkflowActivities'>
         <td [innerText]='activity.assigneeName'>
         </td>
         <td [innertext]='activity.coordinatorName'>
         </td>
         <td>
             <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-exclamation-triangle warning': activity.isCritical, 'fa-share sky': activity.isForwarded}"
                                                    aria-hidden="true"></i> {{activity.serviceName}}
         </td>
         <td [innerText]='activity.activityName'>                                            
         </td>
         <td [innerText]='activity.createdDate | date: "dd/MM/yyyy"'>
         </td>
   </tr>
```

I have checked `pagedWorkflowActivities` that is populating new column, still I am getting this error.

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't
>   bind to 'innertext' since it isn't a known property of 'td'. ("eName'>
>                                           
>                                           ][innertext]='activity.coordinatorName'>
>                                           
>                "): WorkflowDashboardComponent@72:44 Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'innertext' since it isn't a known
>   property of 'td'. ("eName'>
>                                           
>                                           ][innertext]='activity.coordinatorName'>
>                                           
>                "): WorkflowDashboardComponent@72:44
>       at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost/HelixWebApp/angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:8530:21)
>       at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost/HelixWebApp/angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16905:53)
>       at eval (http://localhost/HelixWebApp/angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16828:85)
>       at Set.forEach (native)
>       at compile (http://localhost/HelixWebApp/angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16828:49)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost/HelixWebApp/angular/node_modules/zone-js/dist/zone.js:232:26)
>       at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost/HelixWebApp/angular/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6242:41)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost/HelixWebApp/angular/node_modules/zone-js/dist/zone.js:231:32)
>       at Zone.run (http://localhost/HelixWebApp/angular/node_modules/zone-js/dist/zone.js:114:43)
>       at http://localhost/HelixWebApp/angular/node_modules/zone-js/dist/zone.js:502:57

Though it works fine if I use `{{ }}` for that like

```
<td>{{activity.coordinatorName}}</td>
```

Why it doesn't work with innerText? Do I need to do any settings for that column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes, when programming with Angular, are case sensitive.
You wrote `innertext` instead of `innerText`.

```
<td [innerText]='activity.coordinatorName'>
```

or

```
<td innerText={{activity.coordinatorName}}>
```